# How to set HttpRequest.InputStream value using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a unit test for a WebApi controller that reads a POST body from Request.InputStream.  I need to set the inputstream property of HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream, or set the inputstream's contents.  Here is my unit test code so far, but it keeps throwing exceptions:

```
var originalStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
Stream newStream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes("Test String"));

var propInfo = originalStream.GetType().GetProperty("CanWrite");
propInfo.SetValue(originalStream, true);

newStream.CopyTo(originalStream);

propInfo.SetValue(originalStream, false);
```

I get the following exception on the SetValue line:

```
ArgumentException: Property set method not found
```

Am I going about this all wrong?  My controller reads the input stream and deserializes it into JSON, so I need to be able to insert data into that stream.  I just don't know how to do it.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public abstract bool CanWrite { get; }`. There is not setter on that property.. hence your error.

In your example, `originalStream` will be of type `Stream`. Wrap it in another stream for your test. You aren't testing the `HttpRequest.InputStream`, you're testing the deserialization ...

```
var originalStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
var content = originalStream.ReadToEnd();
```

.. etc.

You may even consider skipping using the request input altogether since you aren't really testing that.

EDIT:

To expand a bit more. You should move this out of the controller action.. do something like the below:

```
public class YourController : Controller {
    private readonly IStreamWrapper _streamWrapper;

    public YourController(IStreamWrapper wrapper) {
        _streamWrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public ActionResult MethodYouAreTesting() {
        var result = _streamWrapper.Process(HttpRequest.InputStream);
    }
}

public class Tests {
    public void YourTestMethod() {
        var controller = new YourController(new FakeStreamWrapper()); // mock perhaps?
        // Asserts here for the controller action
    }

    public void YourWrapperTester() {
        var wrapper = new RealStreamWrapper();
        // test Process method here..
    }
}
```

Then you can test the stream reading and the deserialization in isolation.

Does that make sense or have I made it more complex? :/

Comment: I'm testing my controller's action.  To get the request body, my controller does Context.Current.Request.InputStream.Read (basically) so I need to be able to set that. I have no way of passing the body into my action. I don't see how your method will work for that.

Comment: This is my point though. I would move the logic into it's own class. Inject that into the controller.. and use that to test the action. You would pass the `InputStream` into this separate class that wraps it in a more concrete implementation. What you're doing is much harder than it needs to be. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you, but how do I have the InputStream read the content I'm defining in my test method? I see how your way works, but I don't understand how to tell the InputStream what to read.

Comment: It doesn't have to in your test. Your fake/mock can just instantiate a new stream to test with. In the real implementation, it will use the `InputStream` (because of the injected dependency this is possible). These mock instances would pass in null streams, empty streams, etc during your test. This is fine (I think) because you aren't testing the stream.. you're testing the content. So whether it's the `InputStream` or not **in your test**.. is irrelevant.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead preach - this is perfect testing scenario - OP is testing too many implementation details and just needs to inject some dependencies to handle this instead

Answer (score 0):

The InputStream is a read-only stream.

There are several ways. To start with the simplest:

Create an instance of a StreamReader and call ReadToEnd() on InputStream to get the data being sent.

Once you have the contents, you can modify as needed before doing your JSON conversion.

Again, this is the simplest, least elegant way to do what you want, but it should work.